# How to get value of multiple input fields in angular4?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have defined input fields inside a mat-table. I want to access those values in component.ts file on click of a **Next** button. I've already a method on click of a button but can't think of a way to access input values. I also tried to specify name attribute but it will be same for each input tag.

HTML code:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="npm">
                  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  fxFlex = "15" style="margin-left: 1%;padding-left: 1%;">NPM</mat-header-cell>
                  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" fxFlex = "15"> 
                      <span style ="white-space: nowrap">
                          <input decimal = "true" value= '{{this.selectedAccount.occupancy.npm}}'  style ="display:inline-block; width:55%" #npmValueEntered  required> 
                      </span>
                  </mat-cell>
</ng-container>


<button mat-button [disabled] = "stepTwoFormGroup.invalid || overPercentage || disabledButtons" (click)="submit(stepper)" >Next</button>
```

Comment: Please see Template driven forms: https://angular.io/guide/forms

Comment: Reactive forms is the way to go: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear how you need to access those values. But a simple solution is to bind the inputs to the data using ngModel instead of initializing the value from the data:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="npm">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  fxFlex = "15" style="margin-left: 1%;padding-left: 1%;">NPM</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" fxFlex = "15"> 
        <span style ="white-space: nowrap">
            <input decimal = "true" [(ngModel)]='this.selectedAccount.occupancy.npm'  style ="display:inline-block; width:55%" #npmValueEntered  required> 
        </span>
    </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

Your `submit` function can then access the value via `this.selectedAccount.occupancy.npm`.

But using forms as suggested in the comments may give you better control if you need it.

Comment: As the code specifies, there will be more than one input fields on the UI. How can I bind multiple values using [(ngModel)]? It will be easy if I can store these values in an array in typescript code.

Comment: My code sample shows you how to bind values using ngModel - it works the same for one field/value as it does for multiple fields/values. You can bind to the original data object as shown, an array, or whatever you want. You could also use template or reactive forms. They are all different ways to bind and control data. You haven't shown what you intend to do with the values - in other words what does your next() function need to do? More code would be helpful, but it sounds like you just need to do some reading to get yourself familiar with forms and data binding concepts in Angular.